# Is using a StatelessWidget without a const constructor better than using a StatefulWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget, statelesswidget

The question is what are the implications of having a `StatelessWidget` without a const constructor, like this:

```
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyStatelessWidget({super.key});

  final GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

Compared to a normal `StatefulWidget`:

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

I tried to find answers, but most are just people guessing which one is preferable. Some say that the lack of const in the Stateless make it worse than a Stateful, others that Stateless are always cheaper compared to Stateful, and if no mutable state or lifecycle methods are used, Stateless is always the way. What is the correct response? Is there any concrete explanation on why one is better than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific case (using a `GlobalKey`), it is better to use a `StatefulWidget`.

The state of a `StatefulWidget` will persist be reused by the framework. It means that

```dart
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

for 1 instance of your state, the state and its `globalKey` will be reused and remain *"the same instance"* through the multiple rebuilds of your widget tree.

---

If you were to use a `StatelessWidget`:

```dart
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyStatelessWidget({super.key});

  final GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

a new `globalKey` would be created at each build (and never reused) because at each build, the framework recreates a new instance of your widget (but not necessarily a new state):

```dart
  // A build method somewhere:
  return MyStatelessWidget(); // <- Creates a new instance of `MyStatelessWidget` and therefore a new `GlobalKey globalkey`
```

Comment: That's great! I knew that GlobalKey's needed to be in a Stateful somehow, I just didn't know the reasons. What about other situations that make a StatelessWidget non-const? How does it compare to a StatefulWidget? I instinctively think that the lack of const is always worse, but I don't have a lot of arguments to argue for it or to compare it to the cost of using a Stateful.

Comment: I don't think you can compare _"non-const"_  stateless and stateful widgets. If you need to store something in a state (a property that should persist through builds and/or can be mutated), use a stateful widget, if not use a stateless widget.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess the most popular offending ones I found were GlobalKeys or TextFieldControllers in a StatelessWidget, and your answer answers why that's not a good idea.